# How can I clear data in a GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have 3 `GridViews` in my page.

Using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event I put `GridView2` and `GridView3` data in `GridView1`
but when I restart my application `GridView1` data is still persisted in browser.

I used a session variable to store the data. How can I clear `GridView1`

Answer (score 6):

You can try to clear the GridView1 itself every time you start the application:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = null;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before restarting your application, you've got to clear out your sessions if that's how you're storing the data.  Clearing these session variables will clear your gridview.

Inside of your page load, you can do this.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  Session["mySessionVariable"] = null;
  //...do this for each session variable you need to clear.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a new dataset or null value in your session.