# Differences clear function of gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datasource

[How can I clear data in a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252868/how-to-clear-gridview)  is appeared

```
     GridView1.DataSource = null;
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

I want to Know difference of

```
     GridView1.Clear();
```

two function of  GridView1.Clear()  and GridView1.DataSource = null.I have no error which clear  of syntax of GridView1.Clear().

```
Public Sub Clear()
    Data.Dispose()
    Data = New DataSet
    MyBase.DataSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

I wrote new class of gridview  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Vb class called  my clear function in its class.Sorry,gridview.Clear() is not have.

Comment: I don't see any Clear() method for GridView.

Comment: @ZarNge: I guess you mean GridView.Rows.Clear();

Comment: Sorry,Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any Clear() method listed for [GridView Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_methods.aspx).

If you want to clear the current rows in a GridView, the answer you linked to above is the way to do it:

```
'VB.NET
GridView1.DataSource = Nothing
GridView1.DataBind()

//C#
GridView1.DataSource = null;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If the above isn't working for you, please update your question with the code and what error, if any, you're seeing.

Comment: You used a backtick for your VB comment =)  +1 though, this is exactly right.

Comment: Oops - VB comment fixed.  Thanks :)

Comment: I think perhaps the OP was making sure there *truly is no `GridView.Clear()` function*, and that the way you pointed out is the right way.

Comment: Vary good point - I hadn't looked at it from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the rows of a gridview
you can use this:
Gridview1.Rows.Clear();